# Tag synonym request: [preferences] -> [settings]

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-synonyms

I think [settings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/settings) and [preferences](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/preferences) should be synonyms.

"Settings" is a more general term that applies to driver settings, program settings, system settings, etc. "Preferences" is a term that usually refers to *program settings*; for example, the GUIs of most programs in Ubuntu call the program's settings "preferences". Nonetheless, many people still call those "settings" rather than "preferences". So if we want separate tags based on this distinction, they would need to have more descriptive names like [system-settings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/system-settings).

Since "preferences" is a subset of "settings", I think [preferences](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/preferences) should be a synonym of [settings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/settings).

Comment: Both tags are bad... we should be removing them.

Comment: @Braiam What about questions about [tag:settings]? **Cerran** - Settings is probably more relevant... so if anything, [tag:preferences] should be a synonym to [tag:settings].

Comment: @wilf That's fine. My point is that "settings" and "preferences" are often used to describe the same thing, so why have two separate tags? Because of this ambiguity, there are even several questions with both tags. If they are different, then they need to be obviously different. Making [tag:preferences] a synonym of [tag:settings] is fine by me.

Comment: @wilf Settings/preferences of what!? Of unity? We have a tag. Of apache? we have a tag. Of firefox? We already have the firefox tag. Settings could be anything the same as preferences, both tag needs to be removed out our system.

Comment: Of course, then you start having problems with other tags - e.g. [tag:system-settings]. @Braiam - still relevant - more relavant than [tag:gnome-settings-daemon]

Comment: @Braiam I don't have enough experience here to make that call. If they need to be removed, so be it. But as long as they're here, they should be synonyms. I'm not arguing for their existence.

Comment: Synonyms are for tags that hold some value. Those tags were possibly created for people writing system<space>settings. They were meant to create system-settings tag but failed due how the tag are created. There are a bunch of tags created that way that the only action is removing.

Comment: @Braiam - currently there are 376 settings tags, but there are only 125 system-settings tags...

Comment: @wilf Updated the question, although it may be that Braiam has a point: namely, that we should just have more specific tags instead of these general ones.

Comment: @wilf is obvious, since the system suggest "settings" tag to anything that you write with settings. System Settings is an obscure name of something that most people just call Settings (somewhat) or the thing were you change your preferences.

Comment: Alright... Alright... There just tags y'know

Comment: @Braiam I disagree (unless I misunderstood your point). "System Settings" are the options that can be accessed via power cog > System Settings. I wouldn't call Firefox settings, driver settings, or any other settings not found in the "System Settings" menu "system settings". "Settings" is a much broader term than "system settings", and this is obvious if you look at the types of questions tagged with each of those tags.

Comment: "The Ubuntu **[tag:System-settings]** is often referred to the *GNOME system settings*. Use this tag if you have trouble using the **System Settings** in Ubuntu." there's already a tag for that preference. Whatelse? Settings by itself doesn't help to categorize a bunch of questions within a common topic. If you check the tag relationship you will see that the first 4 tags are version specific and version specific tags are reserved mostly for hardware problems.

Comment: @Braiam Right. I think we're saying the same thing, so I guess I did indeed misunderstand your previous comment.